# How to make left align & right align have the same space in array

Tags: align, arrays

```
    \begin{array}{rl}
    s &≥ 1/x \\
    1 - s &≥ 1/y
    \end{array}
```

[image]

How can I make the spacing before and after ≥ to be the same? (I am rendering using KaTex https://katex.org/)

Comment: Don't do that with `array`: use `align*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both an `array` and an `aligned` environment to achieve results that will look very similar. Be aware, though, that the contents of the `array` environment will be typeset in inline math mode, while those of the `aligned` environment will be typeset in display math mode -- and will also be spaced more loosely.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}             % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\usepackage{amsmath}           % for aligned env.
\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next instruction to the current group
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
$\begin{array}{rCl}
    s     &\ge& 1/x \\
    1 - s &\ge& 1/y
 \end{array}$
\endgroup

\medskip
$\begin{aligned}
    s     &\ge 1/x \\
    1 - s &\ge 1/y
 \end{aligned}$
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code would be wrong also in standard LaTeX.

```
\begin{align*}
s &≥ 1/x \\
1-s &≥ 1/y
\end{align*}
```

This requires `amsmath` on the LaTeX side.

[image]